# quote marks in oracle PL/SQL cursor select

Tags: oracle, plsql

In oracle PL/SQL I am trying to use a dynamically created query for the select statement

```
v_sql := 'SELECT * FROM dba_db_links@DBL_'||v_source||'_'||v_target||'_1';

FOR c2 IN (v_sql)
LOOP
  v_username := c2.username;
```

This is giving the following error on compile:

> [Error] PLS-00103 (21: 12): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOOP"
>   when expecting one of the following:   * & - + / at mod remainder rem
>   ..  ||    multiset year day

Comment: No-no-no. Only explicitly declared cursors can be used in `FOR` cursor loop and you are trying to use just a string literal where explicitly declared cursor is expected. If there is a need to form a select statement dynamically, you need to use cursor  variables(ref cursors) and simple `LOOP` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Do you have an example of how this would be done?

Comment: Sure. [Native dynamic SQL with OPEN-FOR, FETCH, and CLOSE Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#i13057)